# Recursive Template Instantiation failed with tuples

Tags: c++, templates, c++-concepts

I have the following code that iterates through the types of a `std::tuple` and concatenates their names as strings.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>

template<typename types_T, int n, typename T>
concept tuple_element_is = (std::is_same<typename std::tuple_element<n, types_T>::type, T>::value); 

template<typename types_T, int n>
    requires tuple_element_is<types_T, n, float>
constexpr const std::string foo() {
    if constexpr (n < std::tuple_size<types_T>::value - 1) {
        return "float" + foo<types_T, n + 1>();
    } else {
        return "float";
    }    
}
template<typename types_T, int n>
    requires tuple_element_is<types_T, n, int>
constexpr const std::string foo() {
    if constexpr (n < std::tuple_size<types_T>::value - 1) {
        return "int" + foo<types_T, n + 1>();
    } else {
        return "int";
    }
}

auto t0 = foo<std::tuple<int>, 0>();
auto t1 = foo<std::tuple<float>, 0>();

auto t2 = foo<std::tuple<int, int>, 0>();
auto t3 = foo<std::tuple<int, float>, 0>();
//auto t4 = foo<std::tuple<float, int>, 0>(); -- does not compile
auto t5 = foo<std::tuple<float, float>, 0>();

auto t6 = foo<std::tuple<int, int, int>, 0>();
auto t7 = foo<std::tuple<int, int, float>, 0>();
//auto t8 = foo<std::tuple<int, float, int>, 0>(); -- does not compile
auto t9 = foo<std::tuple<int, float, float>, 0>();
//auto t10 = foo<std::tuple<float, int, int>, 0>(); -- does not compile
//auto t11 = foo<std::tuple<float, int, float>, 0>(); -- does not compile
//auto t12 = foo<std::tuple<float, float, int>, 0>(); -- does not compile
auto t13 = foo<std::tuple<float, float, float>, 0>();
```

The instantiation `t4, t8, t10, t11, t12` do not compile and produced this error:

```
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note: constraints not satisfied
In substitution of ‘template<class types_T, int n>  requires  tuple_element_is<types_T, n, float> constexpr const string foo() [with types_T = std::tuple<float, int>; int n = 1]’:
   required from ‘constexpr const string foo() [with types_T = std::tuple<float, int>; int n = 0; std::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’
   required from here
   required for the satisfaction of ‘tuple_element_is<types_T, n, float>’ [with types_T = std::tuple<float, int>; n = 1]
 note: the expression ‘std::is_same<typename std::tuple_element<(long unsigned int)n, types_T>::type, T>::value [with n = 1; types_T = std::tuple<float, int>; T = float]’ evaluated to ‘false’
```

The last `note` is interesting, because it is true that this expression evaluates to `false`, but he used the float variant for the second call.
Maybe I'm using it wrong, but the compiler should re-check the requirements for each recursive call of `foo` and select the correct substitution, in this case `int`.
More interestingly, it works the other way around for `t3, t7`
Note that calling `foo<std::tuple<float, int>, 1>();` directly also works.

I have tested it with both GCC and clang and they produce the same [result](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAMykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxAFmpAAOqAqETgwe3r4ByanpAqHhUSyx8f6JdpgOGUIETMQEWT5%2BgVU1AnUNBEWRMXEJtvWNzTltwz1hfaUDFQCUtqhexMjsHOb%2BYcjeWADUJv5uBACeSZgA%2BgTETIQKB9gmGgCCG1s7mPuHBF5J9PePLzMmwY2y8ewObgUVzCwH%2BzwBBEwLF%2BTEREJOZ2YbF2GMwCnOABVSLswgRdgxibisR8CXCnmgQZgkmTvr8Lph6GxBOc8ApPgARXYQKHoEAgXnnBSsTDo06MaW7EVi1n0c4cpGMAgQik4uX42n%2BbDKuXEg1GkAANzEXkwcwOFn28OeiORBjRXzl1N1Z31xNJ5LpuyDu2ImAAjl48KG%2BSr2ZzNTy7h6fYTiTqqLRUKi6QyoZhVEliLtc2SlSAocQYbt%2BKgIHN9gB2KzPYMkqjFgR5gtFiAMT5uRUEUUgWOSvAALxlybxhPuYqt3g%2BAFpdlx6yYmwDW63Q99iH3zGYM1mtWYzPtLNXUKhZSmieSLw6uPc6/at8GN4KOUpG82ntvg13ZYDzPY9szPN8Ww/BtBQ/eEYIRJEUXdI5PQVXFfRJQQA0Nd8g1DCMozxHEflVdUuQIRNbxne8dVJHNO0RbsOwYKFB2HCsqxrOtfzwtsWK7QshQPQ52OVUiLjSSdqP1OdLWtZdV3XTcoIAoD9wvMx6LPR8rxvadMJAp8Xztfw/1bT9dm/D4N3MgCQ0wPcQK0wRD0g/9oP5AFP2854mC8IgcQ0AU9IhMtYwhejDWJDQTPc/zAoILgQprMKh3EtkITArVot2WLDVfMzfKeBLUBxc8DkFVLDnCiTIsEP1XNy/LsEKv9SpxfwUuvNLhwiw5SWJbL7hiuKiueAB6CaOoISRuv0yF0pHOrDmyxqcuwUaCtMh0pqXFd0FQYiGFQMk0GROgZT8gKyoIABWebeoyv5VszVEhrejattanbipmgA2R6aqW/q3EGrCCHWka8rG9qbpxBsgcWvqVrBhqIY%2Bk9oZatqASmmaAA4kdqzKBvRtaIex2Hdj2g6jr5E6ztQC6/muxKAE5iZB1HwYp4bmthvHpvhpLgsq0LgZR0m3Ap8Gos2mHtvtGmJv23ZDuO06OxZq6nnxkWuGS8XquR56pxlz71sx7MBaVsyVbVjWGa186kkuoWZq4Cr/CqnrJbNrLLerIP5e%2BtqHbpzWmZ1gFPa642/dN5bpb5oP%2BYVnHfqdF5s4BDgFloTg7t4PwOC0UhUE4NxrGsRUlhWGygR4UgCE0fOFgAaxAO6NH0ThJBLtuK84XgFBAXvW7L/PSDgWAkFdy6yAoCAF/oeJtkMYAuB73uaFoRFiDHiBoiH6IwgaY5OGb86KIAeQYWhL6n0gsBYTfxGf/BQxqC08SH/NqgBTWM3UkHIh60DwNEa4xBjgeCwEPaELAr7TwzEwYACgABqeBMAAHdb6YmQTIQQIgxDsCkEQ%2BQSg1BD10FwfQm8UA10sPoSBY9IALFQMyDIY8OBLlvl1JcIpKqmEsNYMw5d2iOGcBAVwow/B0JCFMEoZQ9ApDSFIzIngWiqPyBo3oyiBh0MkbUCYci9DGM6BMfR/R4hGNMVonIdjujWJmLYhYCh66rD0FcTAwDp6Fw4MXUgpdy6Vw4KoAm/0lz/TmhvIwq47oADoNDJKFNXURzDdi4EICQC8/g6G7A8DrIsGw1y8EnloOYndu69wCQPYJQ8wmj3Hi3NuVS%2B4cDMIPZ%2BTTWlT3ab/Q%2BGQQCSCAA%3D).

Any idea?

Comment: Hm.. Maybe just because not yet being used to concepts, but [this](https://godbolt.org/z/sqv9MYa8v) variant appears more readable to me – just for the case you might like it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clang gives me a very straightforward error message:

```
error: call to function 'foo' that is neither visible in the template definition nor found by argument-dependent lookup
        return "float" + foo<types_T, n + 1>();
                         ^
note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'foo<std::tuple<float, int>, 0>' requested here
auto t4 = foo<std::tuple<float, int>, 0>(); //-- does not compile
          ^
note: 'foo' should be declared prior to the call site
constexpr const std::string foo() {
```

The `int` variant of `foo` is not visible in the `float` variant, and "should be declared prior to the call site". In other words, it should be forward-declared, like this:

```
template<typename types_T, int n>
    requires tuple_element_is<types_T, n, int>
constexpr const std::string foo();
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/b8qr9EoE8)

GCC's error message is a little harder to understand, but it's still relatively straightforward when you're used to template related error messages:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'foo<std::tuple<float, int>, (0 + 1)>()'
   12 |         return "float" + foo<types_T, n + 1>();
      |                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
note: candidate: 'template<class types_T, int n>  requires  tuple_element_is<types_T, n, float> constexpr const std::string foo()'
   10 | constexpr const std::string foo() {
```

It doesn't mention any other candidate, meaning that it only considers the one it can see: the first one. Again, because the second one is not declared by that point.